# Evento de clique em Imagem JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

Tenho um implementação sendo desenvolvida em JavaFx só que me deparei com alguma situação que parecem ser simples, ao designar um Evento a imagem no seu OnMouseClicked do meu FXML tenho o retorno do seguinte erro:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

Ao fazer um teste troquei a Imagem pelo Botão e apliquei no OnMouseClicked também obtive o mesmo retorno, só que em cima do que fiz alterei a chamada do método para o OnAction no botão e ai sim obtive a execução do Evento.

Para aplicar estas situação deve fazer uma chamada diferente de método?

Como o ImagemView não tem a opção OnAction como posso aplicar o Evento a ele?

Segue o código do meu método abaixo:

```
@FXML
public void GravarTransportadora(ActionEvent event){
    char fisjurpessoa = 'J';
    SimpleDateFormat formatador = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    try {
        // CNPJ e IE insert
        pf.inserir(txRazaoSocial.getText(),
                Long.parseLong(txCnpj.getText()),
                Long.parseLong(txIe.getText()),
                (new java.sql.Date(((java.util.Date) formatador.parse(txDataInauguracao.getText())).getTime())),
                fisjurpessoa,
                txNomeFantasia.getText(),
                txSite.getText());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Não terás mais que um método com o mesmo nome, onde cada um deles tem uma lista de argumentos diferente?

Comment: @Zuul nesta classe estou somente este método definido para me certificar de que não seria algo que estivesse interferindo.

Comment: Esta questão de definir um método para uma  ImageView tentei fazer para a navegação entre telas porém sem sucesso também.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O OnMouseClicked não é muito recomendado por não ser genérico, (pois há também o onTouched etc). Mas também daria para usar o mesmo nessa situação.

A melhor forma de criar uma "imagem clicável" em JavaFX é alterar o gráfico de um botão e usá-lo como botão imagem.

Abaixo segue um exemplo completo (e mínimo de como obter tal efeito)

**Principal.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Principal extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Pane p = new Pane();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("documento.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**MeuController.java**

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class MeuController implements Initializable {

@FXML private Button btn;
@FXML private Label label;
int numClicks = 0;
private final Image img = new Image(
        "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/sicons/basic-round-social/256/ember-js-icon.png");

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    ImageView imgview = new ImageView(img);
    btn.setGraphic(imgview);
}

@FXML
private void gravarTransportadora() {
    //Aqui executa o método que for, chamo outro método por frescura.
    alteraLabel();
}

private void alteraLabel() {
    label.setVisible(true);
    label.setText("Ocorreram " + (++numClicks) + " cliques na Imagem");
}
}
```

**documento.fxml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="MeuController">
    <children>
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="123.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Ocorreram X cliques na Imagem" visible="false">
            <font>
                <Font size="25.0" />
            </font>
        </Label>
        <Button fx:id="btn" layoutX="192.0" layoutY="121.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#gravarTransportadora">
            <graphic>
                <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="107.0" layoutY="74.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
            </graphic>
        </Button>
    </children>
</Pane>
```